# Input-directives: How to adapt pristine and dirty?

Tags: angularjs, input, angularjs-directive

I builded different directives for entering data (like calendars, colo picker, ...). I would like to give this elements the same behaviour, which the commmon input elmenets have (pristine, dirty). Is there a way to realize that (maybe through inheritance or similar)? If not, anyone has a good idea how to code that proper, so it fits well in well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your directive doesn't use `ng-model` internally you have to create that yourself. So if your directive just wraps a textfield that is editable and has some extra features, it's a good idea to still use `ng-model` since it gives you those extra things. So something like this:

The HTML:

```
<my-input my-model="model1">
```

And the JS:

```
myModule.directive('myInput', function() {
    return {
        replace: true,
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            model: '=myModel'
        },
        template: '<div><input type="text" ng-model="model"</div>',
        link: function($scope, elem, attrs) {
            // Add extra features to the input
        }
    };
});
```

With this, your directive automatically gets the pristine/dirty behavior from using `ng-model`. If this isn't an option for you, I'd suggest that you look through the source for NgModelController, specifically the parts about pristine/dirty.

Comment: Thanks Anders! The most directives validation is more complex, some to not even have input fields...but your point is good!

So there is probably no (hopefully in the future) way to fit in a complex directive in this validation-process...I will have a look at the NgModelController.

Thanks!